# How To Create Diagonal Matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 2 8x8 matrices which is P0 & P1,

```
P0 = [a a a a a a a a            P1 = [b b b b b b b b
      a a a a a a a a                  b b b b b b b b
      a a a a a a a a                  b b b b b b b b   
      a a a a a a a a                  b b b b b b b b    
      a a a a a a a a                  b b b b b b b b
      a a a a a a a a                  b b b b b b b b
      a a a a a a a a                  b b b b b b b b
      a a a a a a a a]                 b b b b b b b b]
```

How to create matrix H like these in matlab?

```
H = [P0 P1 0   0   0   0
     0  P0 P1  0   0   0
     0  0  P0  P1  0   0
     0  0  0   P0  P1  0
     0  0  0   0   P0  P1]
```

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: You should provide more details. Is H supposed to be 5x6 regardless of P0 and P1 dimensions?

Comment: In my view this is a nice (and interesting regarding the efficiency) question. The only ambiguity could arise whether he asks for cell arrays or matrices (cf. both current answers). Some people are voting really strange at this question...

Comment: @ardyanlawrence Have you come any further with your problem? Did one of the fine answers in this topic help you? If yes, it would be nice of you to accept the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `P0` and `P1` are matrices, you can store them in cells, with `H` being a `5x6` cell array/matrix.

Here's an example.

```
>> P0 = ones(8)
P0 =
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
>> P1 = ones(8) + 1
P1 =
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
>> H = cell(5,6)
H = 
    []    []    []    []    []    []
    []    []    []    []    []    []
    []    []    []    []    []    []
    []    []    []    []    []    []
    []    []    []    []    []    []
>> [H{:}] = deal(0)
H = 
    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]
    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]
    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]
    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]
    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]

>> H(sub2ind(size(H), 1:size(H,1), 1:size(H,1))) = {P0}
H = 
    [8x8 double]              [0]              [0]              [0]              [0]    [0]
              [0]    [8x8 double]              [0]              [0]              [0]    [0]
              [0]              [0]    [8x8 double]              [0]              [0]    [0]
              [0]              [0]              [0]    [8x8 double]              [0]    [0]
              [0]              [0]              [0]              [0]    [8x8 double]    [0]
>> H(sub2ind(size(H), 1:size(H,1), 2:size(H,2))) = {P1}
H = 
    [8x8 double]              [8x8 double]              [0]              [0]              [0]    [0]
              [0]    [8x8 double]              [8x8 double]              [0]              [0]    [0]
              [0]              [0]    [8x8 double]              [8x8 double]              [0]    [0]
              [0]              [0]              [0]    [8x8 double]              [8x8 double]    [0]
              [0]              [0]              [0]              [0]    [8x8 double]    [8x8 double]

>> H{1,1}
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
>> H{1,2}
ans =
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
```

Usage of the `sub2ind` function if often closely tied to the concept of linear indexing. Here, `sub2ind` is used to find the linear indexes needed to assign values to the diagonal-fields of `H`.

You can find the relevant documentation here:

[cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)

[linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511)

[the sub2ind function](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;

N = 8;
H_width = 6;
H_height = 5;

P0 = ones(N)*a;
P1 = ones(N)*b;

P = [P0,P1];

H = zeros(N*H_height, N*H_width);

for hh = 1:min(H_height,H_width-1)
    H((hh-1)*N+1:hh*N,(hh-1)*N+1:(hh+1)*N) = P;
end

if H_width < H_height
    H((H_width-1)*N+1:H_width*N,end-N+1:end) = P0;
end
```

**Example for N=2**

```
 1     1     2     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     1     2     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     2     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     2     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     1     2     2     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     1     2     2     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     2     2     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     2     2     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     2     2
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     2     2
```

Comment: Who is giving a -1? Oo

Comment: What do you mean? Right now I see you have 0 upvotes and 0 downvotes

Comment: When I wrote the comment it was ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a matrix containing numbers `a` and `b` in two diagonals, and then repeat those numbers in blocks using `kron`:

```
m = 2; %// size of P0, P1
n = 4; %// number of blocks
a = 5;
b = 10;

h = diag(a*ones(1,n)) + diag(b*ones(1,n-1),1);
h(end,end+1) = b;
H = kron(h,ones(m));
```

Result:

```
H =
     5     5    10    10     0     0     0     0     0     0
     5     5    10    10     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     5     5    10    10     0     0     0     0
     0     0     5     5    10    10     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     5     5    10    10     0     0
     0     0     0     0     5     5    10    10     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     5     5    10    10
     0     0     0     0     0     0     5     5    10    10
```

Comment: I like your answer, but: you should allow for the non-diagonal case as well. Please note, that my solution is much faster than this one (although your code is much more elegant!)...

Comment: @matheburg What do you mean, "non-diagonal"?

Comment: E.g. in the question `H` is non-diagonal. Your implementation is diagonal only currently (although it could easily be extended to the non-diagonal case).